# Neo4j Cypher query optimization - APOC Manual Index on Relationship Properties

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

According to the application logic I have implemented own Cypher query builder which creates a complex queries based on the user input from the UI.

This is the example of such queries:

```
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE dg.id = {decisionGroupId} 
MATCH (childD)-[relationshipValueRel2:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(filterCharacteristic2:Characteristic) 
WHERE filterCharacteristic2.id = 2 
WITH relationshipValueRel2, childD, dg 
WHERE   (ANY (id IN {relationshipValueRel21} WHERE id IN relationshipValueRel2.value ))  AND   ( relationshipValueRel2.`property.1.3` = {property2}  ) OR  ( relationshipValueRel2.`property.1.3` = {property3}  )  
WITH childD, dg  
MATCH (childD)-[relationshipValueRel3:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(filterCharacteristic3:Characteristic) 
WHERE filterCharacteristic3.id = 3 
WITH relationshipValueRel3, childD, dg 
WHERE   (relationshipValueRel3.`value` = 'London')  
WITH childD , dg  
SKIP 0 LIMIT 100 
WITH * 
MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[rup:UPDATED_BY]->(up:User)  
RETURN ru, u, rup, up, childD AS decision, 
[ (dg)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(entityGroup)-[:CONTAINS]->(entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup)-[:COMMENTED_FOR]->(childD)
 | {entityId: toInt(entity.id),  types: labels(entity), totalComments: toInt(comg.totalComments)} ] AS commentGroups, 
[ (c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD)
 | {criterionId: toInt(c1.id),  weight: vg1.avgVotesWeight, totalVotes: toInt(vg1.totalVotes)} ] AS weightedCriteria, 
[ (dg)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(chg:CharacteristicGroup)-[rchgch1:CONTAINS]->(ch1:Characteristic)<-[v1:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD) 
 | {characteristicId: toInt(ch1.id),  v1:v1, optionIds: v1.optionIds, valueIds: v1.valueIds, value: v1.value, available: v1.available, totalHistoryValues: v1.totalHistoryValues, totalFlags: v1.totalFlags, description: v1.description, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

With the small number of the `child:Decision`(for example < 1000) it works pretty fast but the performance is noticeably degrades after the data growth.

The primary reason of this are the filtering operation based on the relationship Properties like:

```
WHERE (ANY (id IN {relationshipValueRel21} 
WHERE id IN relationshipValueRel2.value ))  
    AND ( relationshipValueRel2.`property.1.3` = {property2} ) 
    OR  ( relationshipValueRel2.`property.1.3` = {property3} )
```

Please note that this is just a particular case and the query based on the user input can contains tens such condition with (`<, <=, =, >, >=, IN, ALL IN, ANY IN`) operations **where property value can be a single value or arrays**.

Right now I'm thinking how to improve the performance of this query because I expect tens or hundreds of thousands `child:Decision` there. In order to do this I'm looking into [APOC Manual Index on Relationship Properties](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_using_manual_index_on_relationship_properties)

Taking this into account - does it make sense to reimplement my query builder in order to use APOC Manual Index on Relationship Properties for the mentioned filtering operation or it will not help there?

Comment: You can try out the difference with the PROFILE statement in the Neo4j web console.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to try it but it will require a big development effort from my side. Before it I'd like to get some theoretical advise - should I go this way and try it or it will absolute waste of the time and will not help to fix the performance issue.